# XPath: descendants, but not by traversing this node

Tags: xpath, lxml, traversal

I have a tree of nodes which are quite frankly a mess.

```
|-...
|-cat
\-dog
   |- dog *
   |   |- chicken
   |   |     \- cat !
   |   \- cat !
   |         \- cat !
   |             \- dog
   |                 |- cat
   |                 \- ...
   |- cat
   |- dog
   |   \- cat
   \- ...
```

Given that I've selected the asterisked 'dog' node, how can I select only those cats for whom it is the most recent 'dog' ancestor (i.e. those that have an exclamation mark)

Equivalently, how can I get only those cat descendants of the node that can be reached without traversing another dog node?

I'm working in lxml and currently have a bad solution involving disconnecting the graphs by `drop_tree()`-ing all dog nodes.

Comment: This is not possible using XPath. XPath can only access subtrees, not modify them or create new XML nodes. You will either have to use XQuery or XSLT for that.

Comment: @JensErat I'm not intending to modify the tree or create new XML nodes; that's merely the (rubbish) implementation I have at the moment due to not (currently) being able to select the nodes in pure XPath.

Comment: You need to modify something, and if it's not the original XML, its a copy (of a subtree), a new result tree or whatever. You want to remove parts of your resulting subtree which is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use EXSLT's set extensions: http://www.exslt.org/set/. They're available in `lxml` using `namespaces={"set": "http://exslt.org/sets"}` in your XPath expressions.

You could then do something like

```
asteriskeddog.xpath("set:difference(.//cat, .//dog/cat)",
    namespaces={"set": "http://exslt.org/sets"})
```

meaning "all `cat` elements under the current node, except those under a `dog` element under the current node. I've used that trick in some microdata parsing with nested `itemscope` and `itemprop` elements

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need.